# Remove badge (notification count) on home application icons

Tags: applications, notifications, home-screen, notification-icons, app-icons

**How is it possible to disable the "unread notifications count" on app icons, like the Facebook icon here?**

I have an Android 5.0.2 (not rooted) on a Samsung A3 2015.

PS: I have already done this: hold Facebook icon during 2 seconds, swipe to "App  Info", then uncheck the checkbox "Show notifications", but it did not change anything about the notification count **on the icon itself.**

[image]

Comment: I can't check it on my device because I don't own any Samsung phone, but to resolve your issue you can try to uninstall FB, install it again, then **before you log in** type `adb shell pm revoke com.facebook.katana com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ` and `adb shell pm revoke com.facebook.katana com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE` in the command prompt. Then, proceed with login. Of course you need to enable USB debugging and have ADB properly installed on your PC before you begin.